# Tensorflow does not release the memory after session close

Tags: session, tensorflow

I have two models.

Both model A and B works with training and test when I run them separately.
To be more efficient in training two models with same dataset,
I put their running code together.

```
A.training()
A.close_session() # this closes session with sess.close()
B.training()
```

at B.training() it occurs Resource exhausted error!

So it seems like it does not release the memory when I do the sess.close() after A.training(). This 'sess' is an attribute both A and B has separately as well. - meaning, it is being used as self.sess

Is this a bug ? Is there a solution?

.

.

I have googled and read some arguments and only closing session does not release the gpu memory though. How can I release the gpu memory so the next model can use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tensorflow does not like multiple sessions call in the same thread.

One workaround is to put your A.training() and B.training() in different processes.
Here is a quick walkthrough:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def train_func():
        train(
            learning_rate = 0.001
            ...
        )

    p = Process(target=train_func, args=tuple())
    p.start()
    p.join()
```